# How to get Result from database groupBy week in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to get records from the database groupBy Week. I have two data start dates and end dates. Between these two dates, I want to get all the data groupBy weeks
I know my below query is totally wrong. That is just for an idea

```
    Consignment::('created_at',$request->start_date)->where('end_date',$request->end_Date)->groupBy('Week')->get();
```

All the results should be `groupBy` weeks

**Ex:** `week1`, `week2` and etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you do not have wee in column,then you need to create one during query

```php
Consignment::addSelect(DB::raw('week(created_at) as created_at_week'))
    ->where('created_at',$request->start_date)
    ->where('end_date',$request->end_Date)
    ->groupBy('created_at_week')->get()
```